# ¿como puedo controlar mi scroll de un Chatroom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

mi problema es que el scroll se queda en los mensajes que ya pasador y no baja cuando hay un nuevo mensaje los que quiero es controlar el scroll asi como el de facebook si alguen sabe como hacer eso porfavor que me diga Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">



//esto envia los mensages a la base de datos 


        $(document).ready(function() {

            //method to trigger when user hits enter key
            $("#mensaje").keypress(function(evt) {
                if(evt.which == 13) {

                        //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
                         enviar_insert();
                    }

            });
        }); 

    function enviar_insert(){
        var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje").value;

        var paramentros = {
                "mmensaje" : mensaje,
                "pconsulta" : "consulta",
        };


        $.ajax({
            data: paramentros,
            url: 'submit_chat.php?v=<?php echo $id; ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) { 

        }
        });
        limpiar_datos();
    }

/////aqui se eliminan los datos 

        function enviar_DELETE(){
        var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje").value;
        var paramentros = {
                "mmensaje" : mensaje,
                "pconsulta" : "DELETE",
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: paramentros,
            url: 'submit_chat.php?v=<?php echo $id; ?>',
            type: 'POST',
        });
        limpiar_datos();
    }




//tiempo real del chat 1000 es un segundo 
//aqui nos deja ver el chat 
function mostrar_enviado() {
            var parametros = {
            "pconsulta" : "mostrar_mensajes",
        }   


    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: 'submit_chat.php?v=<?php echo $id; ?>',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mostrar_mensaje').html(data);

                var abajo=$("#mostrar_mensaje").prop("scrollHeight");
                $("#mostrar_mensaje").scrollTop(abajo)  

             setTimeout(function(){//time real
                    mostrar_enviado();
            }, (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)))


        },

    });
}   
mostrar_enviado();


//limpia la caja de los mensages    

function limpiar_datos(){
    document.getElementById("mensaje").value="";
}

</script>
```

Comment: No entendí **[nada de tu comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51099/como-puedo-controlar-mi-scroll-de-un-chatroom/51166#comment96802_51166)**. Si desea algo diferente, por favor, **[editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/51099/edit)** y ser más específico en su pregunta

Comment: @Cʜᴜɴ Ese comentario debería ir en la respuesta, no en la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Shareiv He creado un ejemplo de un concepto sobre cómo puedes abordar esto:

```js
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).hasClass('nueva_msg') ) {
        var $newMessage = $('#newMessageAnchor'),
            $msgContainer = $('.messageContainer'),
            $newMessage = $newMessage.position().top + $msgContainer.scrollTop();
        $msgContainer.animate({scrollTop: $newMessage}, 1000);
    }
});

// El código abajo no importa realmente
var addMsgItem = setInterval(function(){
    var numItems = $('.nueva_msg').length;
    $('.nueva_msg').last().after('<div class="nueva_msg">Nueva mensaje!</div>');
    if ( numItems >= 6) {
        clearInterval(addMsgItem);
    }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.messageContainer {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 50vw;
    overflow: auto;
}
.nueva_msg {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageContainer">
    <div class="nueva_msg">último mensaje</div>
    <div class="nueva_msg">otra mensaje</div>
    <div id="newMessageAnchor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genial tu respuesta :-)

Comment: Gracias @CristinaCarrascoAngulo :) Pero parece que el OP no da retroalimentación :(

Comment: tal vez esta ocupado...  :-) esperemos que lo haga

Comment: EL SCROLL HIJO DE SU CODE XD sigue igual mi codigo actualiza con un ID que envia a un file.php y el **after**  no me funciona porque tengo rebisar los datos para ver si es una imagen o nota de audio y ni hablar del SPAM o el hashtag por eso el scroll no lo puedo controlar y ya para hacabar si estaba ocubado con el sistema de amigos

Answer (score 1):

no agrego comentario debido a que no lo tengo permitido aun, aun así necesitaríamos que muestres el código fuente para poder resolver tu problema, por ahora te recomiendo que a tu scroll le agregue el estilo position:

```
static-bottom o fixed-bottom
```

Comment: como hago eso position JS no es mi fuerte el codigo ya lo pungo

Comment: si aun quieres el codigo dime amig¿? si

Answer (score 1):

Podrías enviar el scroll al final de la pagina cuando hayas recuperado el nuevo elemento. De esta forma

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Espero te sirva